# What's the project of choice for compiling GPB to AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, code-generation, protocol-buffers

Inside a Java project I use [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) (GPB) for serializing my objects. I can use the same .proto files in auxiliary Python code, which is great. Now I'm adding a Flex client to the whole thing and I'd like to use the same .proto files once more.

It seems there's a couple of projects out there which compile .proto files to Actionscript. From a few glances at the projects' homepages, it seems to me that [protobuf-actionscript3](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-actionscript3/) is actually the most advanced and most "alive" of these projects.

Has anybody had practical experience with GPB to AS3 compilers and which one(s) can you recommend (or recommend against)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure you want to use GPB, then protobuf-actionscript3 is your best option. It builds on the semi-successful protocol-buffers-actionscript project: http://code.google.com/p/protocol-buffers-actionscript/

If you're open to looking at other formats, there's always Adobe's own AMF3. It seems to have a good amount of community support behind it.

Answer (score 0):

The only choice now is https://code.google.com/p/protoc-gen-as3/. All the other Protobuf/AS3 projects are out-of-date, and lack of features.